# How to compute distances in miles using ST_Distance and ST_Transform

Tags: geospatial, postgis

I have lat/long points in my table and I want to compute distances between them in miles.

Apparently just calling ST_Distance (point1, point2) returns something I don't want (again point1 and point2 are in lat & long). I was advised to use ST_Transform which allows me to do coordinate reference system transformation. But I am so new to this domain I am lost. Please enlighten me (with some example hopefully)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to select a coordinate system that is suitable for your area of interest. Some of them have feets for units, others are in meters. In both cases you would need to transform the found distance to miles.

example where xxxx is a coordinate system using meters, such as UTM:

```sql
select 
  st_distance(
     st_transform(point1.geom, 4326, xxxx),
     st_transform(point2.geom, 4326, xxxx)
  ) *  0.000621371192  as dist_miles;
```

Since you mentionned that you are new to this, selecting the proper coordinate system might be somewhat difficult. It is then easier to revert to computing the distance using the `geography` datatype, i.e. measuring the distance on a round earth, not on a flat representation of it. The result is also in meters and needs to be converted to miles.

```sql
select 
  st_distance(
     point1.geom::geography,
     point2.geom::geography
  ) *  0.000621371192  as dist_miles;
```

Comment: can you give an example of xxxx?

Comment: @pyramation you can get the epsg codes [here](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/?page=2&search=NAD83+%2F+UTM+), for example 26901

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the simple features route with `library(sf)` this is one way.

First, convert your lat-lon data frame into a simple features data frame with `st_as_sf()`.

```
library(sf)

my_data <- data.frame(
    lat = c(87.5, 88.5),
    lon = c(35, 26),
    name = c("A", "B")
)

my_sf <- st_as_sf(my_data,
         coords = c("lon", "lat"), # x, y (order matters)
         crs = 4326)
```

Then you can call `st_distance()` and get a pairwise distance matrix returned.

```
st_distance(my_sf)
Units: m
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,]      0.0 116733.7
[2,] 116733.7      0.0
```

It is returned with the default units (meters) because we set `crs` argument in `st_as_sf()`.

If you want to transform the units to miles you can do it with `units::set_units()`

```
st_distance(my_sf) %>%
    units::set_units(mi)

Units: mi
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  0.00000 72.53493
[2,] 72.53493  0.00000
```